# How do I switch between corresponding .h or .c/.m files in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 3 I could click a button in the top-right corner of the code editor to switch between header and implementation (.c or .m) files. Now in Xcode 4 there is no button like this around the editor. This would be even more useful now than it was with Xcode 3, because I'd like to click a class in the Symbol view to pull up the relevant .h file, then click a button or keyboard shortcut and get to the .m file.

Answer (score 2):

See this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300947/how-do-i-switch-between-the-header-and-implementation-file-in-xcode-4/5300985#5300985) answer.

"Ctrl+Cmd+Up or Down, but the shortcut seems a bit finicky and sometimes stops working, not yet sure when and why."

Comment: Hmm... it seems to work in project or symbol view, unless you're in symbol view and clicked on a protocol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

three finger swipe up & down, I'm loving this!

**EDIT**: ermm, isnt a bit offtopic and should be asked in SO?

Comment: It is a question about Apple software. It's not really about the code aspect of programming, so I think it's OK here. It would probably also be at home on StackOverflow.